# Google Forms script to replace a specific field?

Tags: javascript, forms, replace

I am creating multiple rather lengthy forms that will be used as checklists for an evaluation. Because of the length, I would like to maintain the user interface for creating the forms visually as opposed to writing them.

What I would like to do is insert a piece of code at specific points throughout the forms to include a file uploader. My thought was to place a text field when creating a form in the editor with a specific phase such as "fileupload". This script could then search and replace these fields with the file uploader code when the form is opened.

Does this sound possible? Others have successfully developed the code to upload a file but only used it in a simple written form. The forms I am creating are much to lengthy to take that approach and I feel the editor simplifies the creation process.

Thanks

Comment: please, show some code. It will help the SO community to give you better and faster help

Comment: It is possible, but I am not sure how that would effect your responses spreadsheet

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I am a novice and I am just learning to solve this issue at hand. I have not developed any code but I needed to get a feel for how possible this idea would be. I will continue to pursue the next steps.